# Closure compile Can't find variables after minification

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, google-closure-compiler

I am using closure compiler to create single javascript file for all my code.
I am running my code through PhantomJS.

here is my code

```
function process(inputParams, dataCollector) {
    var webpage = require('webpage').create();
 webpage.open(entityResolvedFilePath, function(status) {
var hasnodes = webpage.evaluate(function() {                      
                        var nodesInfo= (document.getElementsByTagName('requirednode').length;
                        if (nodesInfo) {
                            MathJax.Hub.Register.MessageHook("Math Processing Error",function (message) {
                               throw message;
                           });


                           MathJax.Hub.queue.Push(function() {
                              mathJaxCleaner.cleanMathJaxOutput();
                               window.callPhantom();
                           });

                       }
                           return hasMathNodes;
                       });

                       if (!hasMathTags) {
                           webpage.onCallback();
                       } 
            }
            else {
                webpage.onCallback();
            }
        }
    });
```

I wanted to call cleanMathJaxOutput function inside MathJax.Hub.queue.Push.
It works locally because i am not running minified code locally.
But when i minify this code through closure compile then my code fails with and error that **`reference error could not find mathJaxCleaner`**
This might be happing becasue Phantomjs's webpage.evaluate create a different closure scope where i don't have to global variable mathJaxCleaner.

I have declared cleanMathJaxOutput like this.

```
var mathJaxCleaner = new Object();
mathJaxCleaner.cleanMathJaxOutput =function() {}
```

I have also tried to declare mathJaxCleaner as a function and then attached functions on it's prototype but none of thing worked for me.
After minification code become something like this.

```
var P = {
    A: function() {
        function a(a) {
            a && a.parentNode.removeChild(a)
        }

        function b(a) {
            if (a)
                for (; 0 != a.length;) this.removeNode(a[0])
        }

        function d(a) {
            var b = document.createElement("defs");
            a.insertBefore(b, a.childNodes[0]);
            a = a.getElementsByTagName("use");
            for (var c = 0; c < a.length; ++c) {
                var d = a[c].getAttribute("href");
                b.appendChild(document.getElementById(d.substr(1)).cloneNode(!0))
            }
        }
        for (var c = document.getElementsByClassName("MathJax_SVG"), e = 0; e < c.length; e++) {
            for (var f = c[e], v = f.childNodes, w = 0; w < v.length; w++) "svg" ==
                v[w].tagName && d(v[w]);
            f.style.fontSize = "inherit";
            "inline-block" === f.style.display && (f.style.display = "inline")
        }
      some more code here...
    }
};
```

Function call in minified code look likes **P.A()** 
but at execution time PhantomJS says Reference error Can't find variable: P

How to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you tell us more about mathJaxCleaner?  Where is it coming from? Who makes it? What does it do?  Why are you calling it?  The error you got makes sense because it's nowhere defined in your code.  But just making an object with that name isn't going to do anything useful.

Comment: mathJaxCleaner Is defined in a different file, I have specified list of files to closure compile to compile. mathJaxCleaner removes unnecessary nodes created due to injection of MathJax.js file. I have to use mathJaxCleaner function inside webpage.evaluate function because there only i have access to to document object.

Comment: So mathJaxCleaner should already exist as a global?  If so, you can try to create an externs file that specifies what mathJaxCleaner's type is.  See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-write-an-externs-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it the solution for this problem.

In PhantomJS function inside of webpage.evaluate is not just a closure, it exists inside of another context (that of a webpage) in which all outer variables and function do not exist, but a web page's DOM is available instead.

So I have added my function explicitly in window object.

```
window['myfunctionName'] = myfunctionName;
function myfunctionName()
{
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Closure Compiler with a `compilation_level` of `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`, you have to export the symbols (var, function etc.) you want to be available for the outside world (not compiled).

Use `@export` before or use `goog.exportSymbol(publicPath, object)` after each symbol you need to export.

For that you need to include the closure library and add the following arguments to closure compiler : `--generate_exports --js closure-library-path/closure/goog/base.js`